# priv/static/js/app.js updates randomly when changes Vue files - Phoenix/Elixir/Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a vue.js/Phoenix app. I'm trying to understand how to properly configure the frontend assets. I'm having trouble understanding why my priv/static/js/app.js file keeps updating whenever I Change something in other files. I'm trying to research this behavior but I can't seem to find out any information.

#### app.html.eex

```
<body>
  <%= render @view_module, @view_template, assigns %>
  <script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>
</body>
```

My basic question is how to structure a vue.js app? The fact that I change something in `asset/src` dynamically changes something in `static/js/app.js` seems really strange. Does anybody have resources or answers on what might be happening here or places I can go to learn more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Pawel said, this behaviour might be intentionally configured. There is the watcher specified in `config/dev.exs`:

```
watchers: [
  node: ["node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch", "watch", "--stdin",
  cd: Path.expand("../assets", __DIR__)]]
```

That would be used in development mode to allow so-called “hot reload”: one does not need to reload the application when some changes in assets are made, `app.js` will be rebuilt and reloaded automagically.

There is also `assets/brunch-config.js` file, where one might specify rules of how the resulting `app.js` is being produced. By default is just compiles everything found in `assets` to the single javascript file, but this behaviour might be easily changed (e.g. one might exclude anything from being built into `app.js` and specify their own rules to provide an access to these excluded files.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I'm using webpack though. does that change anything?

Answer (score 0):

As contrary as this might sound, this is exactly the behaviour Phoenix (with Brunch) provides.

The main idea is to implement your JS functionality in `assets/js/app.js`, then Brunch (http://brunch.io/) as a build tool will take the content, compile/transpile and output to `priv/static/js/app.js`.

This means, with default configuration that comes with Phoenix, you can use ES6 in your code in `assets/js/app.js`, but this will be "translated" to executable form (that's understood by browsers), and located in `priv/`. `priv/static` is exposed publicly, and this will be the content available by:

```
<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>
```

To wrap up.

Code in `priv/static` is not meant to be changed by code, it gets there automatically by changes you put under your source control in `assets/`.

If that's any help, you can take a look at one of old blog posts about assets in Phoenix [here](http://phoenixframework.org/blog/static-assets).

Good luck!

Comment: Interesting. I'm using webpack not brunch though

Comment: Conceptually they behave the same. You should amend only files inside your `assets` directory, as it will override corresponding files inside `priv/static`

Answer (score 0):

I have been happy using webpack with Vue as of now. It uses a similar, configurable, `watcher` as the one mentioned by mudasobwa. In Webpack if you touch a file that is in part of the bundle it will recompile the needed files only (which can still be many depending on the dependency graph), probably brunch recompiles all.

I also use Yarn to manage npm, and I always include vuex unless it's really something just basic (although not related to file organisation it does help a lot organising vue on any non-trivial apps). Then

/assets

- js

  - entry point files that I use for webpack output into its own individual bundles/apps
  - folders to organise these, usually /components-views-related, /store-related, /shared-utilities
- css

  - .scss files, divided so that they can be split into "global" styles and individual styles that then are required in each "entry point". Then I use a "general" scss stylesheet on "all pages" and each page the corresponding css bundle where they're needed.

Then on the templates side, I wrote a small, overly complex, brittle, system to just automate the "bundle" that gets loaded on the template (in the html document head) but you can just load each bundle/s where you need them.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using webpack and yarn though.